# Error when using MSGraphClient

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, error, spfx, spfx-extensions

Today I tested some of my apps created with SharePoint framework and they started to show a errors in the webparts and extensions that use MSGraphClient. Before it was working normally.

I am importing the MSGraphClient from sp-client-preview and I get the similar error bellow on more than one tenant.

(***Failed to load component "4d5eb168-6729-49a8-aec7-0e397f486b6e" (SPClientPreview).
Original error: ***loadComponent() returned an empty object for component "4d5eb168-6729-49a8-aec7-0e397f486b6e" (SPClientPreview).).
Original error: {3}
    at t [as constructor] (listview-host-assembly_default_e755154cda130cbe2be1b4ac2da90def.js:77)
    at new t (listview-host-assembly_default_e755154cda130cbe2be1b4ac2da90def.js:342)
    at Function.e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (listview-host-assembly_default_e755154cda130cbe2be1b4ac2da90def.js:342)
    at Function.e.buildLoadComponentError (listview-host-assembly_default_e755154cda130cbe2be1b4ac2da90def.js:342)
    at listview-host-assembly_default_e755154cda130cbe2be1b4ac2da90def.js:342

Is there any update occurring in Microsoft SharePoint online servers?

Comment: Please checkout official [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph) - it's not in preview anymore. They released SPFx 1.6 update in September with some changes, I'm not sure if it affects you or not

Comment: i checked but there is step that we have to use this following method :this.context.msGraphClientFactory. The msGraphClientFactory does not exist. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your webpart use the older SPFX version and you dont have this.context.msGraphClientFactory added in the last version for fix this you have two solution :

- 1st and not the best : Update SPFX on your webpart [Microsft Doc for update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/update-latest-packages) but i try this solution and its a lot of pain :)
- Best solution: update yoeman generator, create a new webpart and add your older code inside the new

Comment: I updated my project following this article https://blog.mastykarz.nl/upgrade-sharepoint-framework-project-office-365-cli/ and i was able import msgraph, but now i getting the following error:
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'filename.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.

I searched for the possible cause but without result.

Comment: Its why i prefer create a new webpart and add my older code inside , whith this project update process you need to edit manually some files in your project and doesnt work all times .

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to SPFX 1.6 and use this line to import library:

```
import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

Same question posted in Technet forum:

[strange error in webparts and extensions that use MSGraphClient](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5dbcd091-3fc9-487d-b42d-e5c0dadd579c/strange-error-in-webparts-and-extensions-that-use-msgraphclient?forum=SP2016)

Comment: I updated my project following this article https://blog.mastykarz.nl/upgrade-sharepoint-framework-project-office-365-cli/ and i was able import msgraph, but now i getting the following error:
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'filename.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.